# Anypoint plateform mock throwing error for json Schema

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

I have created a raml in anypoint platform below is my RAML file

```
#%RAML 0.8
title: es-be-crm-dev
version: 001-dev
#baseUri: http://localhost:8081/api     
baseUri: https://mocksvc.mulesoft.com/mocks/44267573-73b2-4369-8e2d-         3a6abbf20e34/api
traits: 
 - rate-limited: 
   queryParameters: 
   client_id: 
    type: string 
   client_secret: 
    type: string   
schemas:
  - api-request-schema: !include schemas/api-request-schema.json


/teams/{teamId}/teamMembers:
post:
  description: Delete Team Member(s) from specified Team

  headers:
    Accept:
      displayName: Accepted response format
      description: Caller accepted response content Type
      type: string
      example: application/json
      required: true
      default: application/json
    Content-Type:
      displayName: body Mime Type
      description: Caller accepted response content Type
      type: string
      example: application/json
      required: true
      default: application/json
  body: 
    application/json:
      schema: api-request-schema
      example: !include examples/api-request-example.json

  responses:
    201:
      description: Returned when the entity has been successfully created
      headers:
        ETag:
          displayName: Entity Tag
          description: Hash of the previously requested resource
          type: string
          example: asd8asd98hlk209u098asdfmoiun4023
          required: false          
    401:
      description: Returned when the user is not authorized to add a member


delete:
  description: Adds Team Member(s) in specified Team

  headers:
    Accept:
      displayName: Accepted response format
      description: Caller accepted response content Type
      type: string
      example: application/json
      required: true
      default: application/json
    Content-Type:
      displayName: body Mime Type
      description: Caller accepted response content Type
      type: string
      example: application/json
      required: true
      default: application/json

  body: 
    application/json:
      schema: api-request-schema
      example: !include examples/api-request-example.json

  responses:
    201:
      description: Returned when the entity has been successfully created
      headers:
        ETag:
          displayName: Entity Tag
          description: Hash of the previously requested resource
          type: string
          example: asd8asd98hlk209u098asdfmoiun4023
          required: false          
    401:
      description: Returned when the user is not authorized to delete a member
```

below is api-request-example.json

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
   "type": "object",
   "properties": {
  "teamMembers": {
    "type": "array",
     "items": {
     "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "teamMember": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "empID": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "sourceSystemId": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "sourceSystemObjectId": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "empID",
          "sourceSystemId",
          "sourceSystemObjectId"
        ]
      }
      },
      "required": [
      "teamMember"
    ]
    }
  }
  },
 "required": [
"teamMembers"
 ]
}
```

below is Example file

```
 {
  "teamMembers": [{
    "teamMember": {
        "empID": "d3193f53-5f07-e611-80e3-a45d36fc4f90",
        "sourceSystemId": "abc",
        "sourceSystemObjectId": "abc"

    }
    }]
}
```

whenever i try to mock my api in it throws an error with status code 400

```
{
 "error": "schema did not parse: Unexpected token a"
}
```

is there anything that i am missing here ???

Answer (score 0):

Has the error message says mule is not able to parse your schema and this is probably because the ApiKit version you are using does not support aliases.
That's way he says `can't parse a`.

Change it with a direct include

```
schema: !include api-request-schema.json
```

I know is not ideal but is just a little more to write.

Comment: Hi, I saw the alias now, but which version of Mule and ApiKit are you using ?is possible that is not supporting aliases for schemas.

Comment: i am using the latest one .. it is working when i don't use alias btw

Comment: Hi, I think is probably not supported. Updated the answer for clarification